# Blender 2.7 Basic Vertex question

Tags: vertices

Unless my memory completely fails me, I used to be able to do CTRL+R to create a vertex along an edge.

Now, I get the Loop, Slide functionality.

I know I can create the other vertices and delete the ones I don't need but it would be very helpful to add a vertex on occasion.

Did something change during a recent version change or am I remembering incorrectly.

I realize that we need to keep 4 sided polygons as much as possible but sometimes it can be very useful to do that by inserting vertices.

Can anyone help?  I did a lot of Bing searches but the earliest responses I saw were around 2011 and they were suggesting the same thing that I remembered.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Natarthos

Comment: You can also use *Extend Vertices* command (`Alt`+`D`) with vertex selected. For moving it along the edge press `G` once more just after extending to activate *Slide* tool.

Comment: Ctrl+R still works. I think what's tripping you up is the lack of visual feedback (like a colored dot) showing when hovering over the edge of a Triangle. When you click, however, a vertex will be added. This is possibly a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you're meaning correctly, you want to add vertices only on a specific edge, and not to add an entire loop.

To do that, select the edge, then subdivide using the button on the Tools Panel, or the shortcut <kbd>W</kbd> --> Subdivide. You can then edit the number of subdivisions through the Last Operator Panel (bottom of the Tools Panel), or the F6 menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this will work quite nicely!  Much appreciation for your very timely and detailed answer.

Comment: @NatarthosSothratis Welcome to the site :) If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, consider [marking it as accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)